# io_context not blocking for async_connect

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to run a simple client, server script using boost asio.

The code for my connect() function is below which is called in my main.cpp once.

```
void connect(){
                if (!connected)
                {
                    sock = std::make_unique<tcp::socket>(io_context);
                    sock->async_connect(*endpoint,connectHandler);
                    connected = true;  io_context.run();


                }

            }
```

My connectHandler() simply prints a message saying connection established.

My main method looks like this:

```
    Client client(argv);
    client.connect();

    while (graphic.Window()) //While program running.
    {
        //Poll our events.
        graphic.drawAndUpdate();
        
    }
```

I thought that using async_connect places the connect operation on a queue and then io_context blocks until that is completed but my main method continues to loop with no block.
I start my main.exe and it loops and then after around 5 seconds I start my server.exe and I don't get any message even though my server listens for connections?
I know I could use a non asynchronous connect for the client but I'm just trying to grasp how io_context works here.

Comment: Where did you find anything suggesting that `async_connect` ever causes anything to block (except perhaps internally it might block a service thread that has nothing to do)? The whole point of async functions is that they don't block anything and so you can have many of them pending. Also, you don't show the code for your main method, so we can't tell whether it should block or not.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply async_connect blocks but the fact that io_context.run() blocks until all async tasks are finished. But it doesn't. My main method doesn't have anything else, it just doesn't block after client.connect() which calls io_context.run() with a pending task.

Answer (score 0):

```
io_context.run();
```

Blocks until it runs out of work.

Once it did, you **need** to call `io_context.restart()` before you can use it again. Otherwise `run()` will simply immediately return without doing anything.

This is documented.

Also

- there's little value in async operations if you always block on them right away
- consider actually integrating the Asio event loop with your GUI framework, by doing something like

  ```
  while (graphic.Window()) //While program running.
      {
          //Poll our events.
          io_service.poll();
          graphic.drawAndUpdate();
      }
  ```

Finally, `io_service` has been long deprecated. Consider `io_context`.